# Why is string interpolation named the way it is?

Tags: string, interpolation, terminology

The term interpolation is usually used in mathematical functions when determining a function for given values, which makes perfect sense. I don't see how that applies for strings, what is being interpolated? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The idea is that you have bounds and you have to figure out what goes in the middle.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_(manuscripts)

Answer (score 5):

Interpolation in mathematics is simply working out the things *between* two points<sup>(a)</sup>. For example, [cubic spline fitting](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Cubic_Spline_Interpolation) over a series of points will give you a curve of some description (I consider a straight line to be a degenerate curve here so don't bother pointing out that some formulae generate such a beast) between each set of points, even though you have no *actual* data there.

Contrast this with *extrapolation* which will give you data *beyond* the endpoints. An example of that is seeing that, based on history, the stock market indices rise at `x` percent per annum so, in a hundred years, will be *much* higher than they are now.

So it's a short step to the most likely explanation as to why variable substitution within strings is called interpolation, since you're changing things *within* the bounds of the data:

```
xyzzy="42"
plugh="abc${xyzzy}xyz"
// now plugh is equal to "abc42xyz"
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The actual roots of the word are Latin `inter + polare`, those translating to "within" and "polish" (in the sense of modify or improve). See [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/interpolate) for more detail.